# dlsym-like behaviour for static linked libraries

Tags: c, linux, ld

I am trying to write sort of a dispatch function in C that should receive a string consisting of a function name, and afterwards from inside the dispatch function to be able to call the function whose name is specified in the argument received. The whole point is that I do not want to define the function in a dynamically loaded library. The flow should be something like this.

file1.c

```
void hello()
{
   fprintf(stderr,"Hello world\n");
}

void myfunc()
{
   mydispatch("hello");
}
```

file2.c

```
void mydispatch(const char *function)
{
...
}
```

I know this structure may be sort of weird, but I was mainly wondering if one could do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BFD to get the addresses at runtime from symbol names.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <bfd.h>
#include <string.h>

void func1(int n)
{
    printf("%d\n", n);
}

void * addr_from_name(char * filename, char * symname)
{
    bfd *        ibfd;
    asymbol **   symtab;
    symbol_info  info;
    void *       symaddress = NULL;
    long         size;
    long         syms;
    unsigned int i;

    bfd_init();

    ibfd = bfd_openr(filename, NULL);
    bfd_check_format(ibfd, bfd_object);

    size   = bfd_get_symtab_upper_bound(ibfd);
    symtab = malloc(size);
    syms   = bfd_canonicalize_symtab(ibfd, symtab);

    for(i = 0; i < syms; i++) {
        if(strcmp(symtab[i]->name, symname) == 0) {
            bfd_symbol_info(symtab[i], &info);
            symaddress = (void *)info.value;
        }
    }

    bfd_close(ibfd);
    return symaddress;
}

int main(void)
{
    void (*func)(int) = addr_from_name("/homes/mk08/Desktop/lala", "func1");
    printf("%p\n", func);
    func(5);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In this case, I hardcoded `filename`, but it is trivial to get it dynamically. Assuming your source/binary is called `lala`, you can compile and run like so:

```
gcc -Wall -std=gnu99 lala.c -o lala -lbfd && ./lala
```

On my system, this prints:

```
0x400814
5
```

Note that this method requires an intact symbol table. To reduce overhead, you can re-use the code above in an initialisation routine. In there, you would store a mapping from function names to addresses. This results in a one-off cost for generating a lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do it like this:

```
void mydispatch(const char *function)
{
    if (!strcmp(function, "hello")
        hello();
    else if (!strcmp(function, "goodbye")
        goodbye();
}
```

and you'd be in good company; many a language interpreter was built this way in the olden times.

As far as doing something more dynamic: the necessary runtime structures simply aren't there for statically-linked libraries. Whatever you do, you're going to have to create some kind of dispatch table (like what I've shown here) manually or automatically -- but you're going to have to do it yourself.

Comment: Yeah but, this would defeat the whole purpose, and moreover it would result in a very messy code when you're facing let's say 20+ methods that could be dispatched.

Comment: Well, as I said, if you're clever about it you could do it automatically -- i.e., the dispatcher could be generated by a script, or at the very least you could write it as successive applications of a simple macro.

Comment: I don't actually see how you could do such a thing during runtime. The whole idea with the 2 file was so that you could compile file2.c at an earlier time, and then use it later on without needing to modify it. For example you could have a _char **_ of available methods, which could be static in file2.c and you could append to id by some functions and then the dispatch could check your call for validity. If you decide to use a script/macro you have to recompile every time.

Comment: Yes, the script or macro are a way to avoid writing the code by hand, not a way to do things dynamically. As I said, the runtime mechanisms for dynamic lookup are simply not available for functions in static libraries. There's no way to call such a function other than to have compiled code which branches to the right offset in the library. Ultimately a call to (or at least a *mention of*) each static function has to be compiled into your code.

Comment: I suppose you could create a table of function name and function address yourself, and then lookup/branch via that table. As those offsets are computed during linking, again, it's unclear how you could do it at runtime.

Comment: If the goal is just to keep file2 insensitive to changes, then you could have a global, dynamically allocated table of function name/function pointers, and have file2 operate by searching it. file1 could populate that table at runtime, at least in the sense that hard-coded function name/pointer pairs could be inserted in the table at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are seaching the following kind of solution:

file1.c:

```
void myfunc()
{
   my_function_type fun = search_function( "operation1" );
   fun(); 
}
```

tools.h:

```
typedef void (*my_function_type)( void );
void register_function( my_function_type fp, const char* name );
my_function_type search_function( const char* name );
```

file2.c:

```
static void mydispatch( void )
{
...
}    

static void __attribute__ ((constructor)) register_functions()
{
     register_function( mydispatch, "operation1" );
}
```

In that solution you don't need to compile old files again, when you add functionality.
Just compile the new file and link.